# Why does syslog have two different function declarations?

Tags: c++, c, linux, overloading, glibc

According to the Linux manual pages [1](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html) and [2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html), the function `syslog` has two different function declarations as follows:

`int syslog(int type, char *bufp, int len);`

`void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);`

However, other than C++, there is no function overloading in C.

How to explain the fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is defined in section 2 (`syslog(2)`) of the manual pages (*), thus a system call. The other one is from section 3 (`syslog(3)`) thus a C library function.

So "technically" they are different functions that happen to have the same name (albeit they are related of course, as (3) is using (2)).

(*) See [manual page sections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3587/3971).

Comment: What if I include the two header files in one source file?

Comment: I would assume that there is no sensible way to do that. Hence that the manual page for `syslog(2)` says, that glibc exposes this "function" as `klogctl`. If you look at the actual `sys/klog.h` [source](https://github.com/search?q=sys%2Fklog.h&type=Code) you will see that there is no function named `syslog` defined. To learn more about syscalls see [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Answer (score 3):

The first is a system call not a c function, it is wrapped in the function `klogctl`, the second is a c function.

Calling a system call is much more involved than [simply invoking a function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), the declaration in the man pages is simply a short cut showing you the system call name and the arguments it expects in a syntax that programmers are familiar with.